# Using getUTCHours and adding the UTC offset in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

Can someone explain how to add the UTC offset to getUTCHours so that it returns the correct hours?  I know that it is currently 9:36pm MST.  We currently are on Daylight saving time so we have a UTC offset of -6.  So I would expect that if I add the offset to getUTCHours then I should get 21.  Instead I get -2.  What am I doing wrong?

```
var offset=-6;
var dt = new Date();
var h=dt.getUTCHours();
var hour=h+offset;
console.log(hour);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the 29th in UTC time so the hours are only 4. Compare the getDate vs the getUTCDate of your date object - if they are different increment your hours by 24.

```
var offset=-6;
var dt = new Date();
var h=dt.getUTCHours();
var hour=h+offset;
if(dt.getDate()!=dt.getUTCDate()){
    hours+=24;
}
console.log(hour);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure on why you are doing this, just a hint:

```
var dt = new Date(2015,0,1,21,30);
var ltm = ( dt.getUTCHours()*60 ) - dt.getTimezoneOffset();
var localTimeString = Math.floor(ltm / 60) + ":" + (ltm % 60);//21:30
```